# Gradient´s direction of constraints (Lagrange multiplier)

Tags: vector-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to understand Lagrange´s multiplier method. I have one question. I´ ve seen sketches where the gradient of function f and constraint g point to the same direction at a possible extreme value. However, there are also sketches where g´s gradient points to the opposite direction of f´s gradient at the possible extreme value. Is there any meaningful interpretation of the direction of the constraint´s gradient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. Suppose that you have two constraints $g_1$ and $g_2$, with $g_2=-g_1$. You want to find the local extremes of the restriction of $f$ to the set $\{x\in\Bbb R^n\mid g_1(x)=c\}$, for some $c\in\Bbb R$, which is *equal* to the set $\{x\in\Bbb R^n\mid g_2(x)=-c\}$. If $p$ is such that $\nabla f(p)=\lambda\nabla g_1(p)$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, then $\nabla f(p)=-\lambda\nabla g_2(p)$. So, either $\nabla f(p)$ and $\nabla g_1(p)$ have the same direction or $\nabla f(p)$ and $\nabla g_2(p)$ have the same direction. But, again, its the same set. So, having the same direction or opposite directions means nothing.

Comment: I think this answer is a bit misleading. There is an clear geometric meaning to the tangent cone and under certain conditions, e.g. if the gradients of all active constraints are linearly independent, it is equal to the linearizing cone wich is defined in terms of the constraint gradients.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea of this method is that in the point $p$ of possible constrained extremum a derivative of $f$ along any curve passing through $p$ is zero at $p$. Hence the gradient of $f$ belongs to the orthogonal complement of a tangent space to $g$ in $p$. Hence it can be represented as a linear combination of gradients of functions defining the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment (everything taken with a grain of salt since I'm just studying this subject myself):

Let $$\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb R^n : g(x)\geq 0, h(x) = 0\}$$ be the admissible set for continuously differentiable constraints $g: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ and $h: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^k$.

Let $y\in\Omega$ and $g_i: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be active in $y$, i.e. $g_i(y)=0$, and $\nabla g_i(y)\neq0$. Then there exists a neighbourhood of $y$ such that the set $M=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:g_i(x)=0\}$ is a $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$. In $y$, the vector $\nabla g_i(y)$ will be orthogonal to $M$ and pointing in the direction of increasing values of $g_i$, that is into the set $\{x\in\mathbb R^n: g_i(x)\geq0\}$.

As an example take the set above the parabola:
$$\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb R^2: g(x) \geq 0\}$$
where $g(x)=x_2-x_1^2$.

We have
$$\nabla g(x)=\begin{pmatrix} -2 x_1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

In the origin the gradient is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, pointing up vertically as expected. In $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ it is $\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, in $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$ it is $\begin{pmatrix} -4 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and so on. The further we travel on the parabola the more horizontal the gradient becomes, always pointing into $\Omega$ orthogonal to its boundary.